# Homomorphism given by $x \mapsto x^p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $G$ be a group of order $p^3$. Suppose we have already proved that the map $\varphi: G \rightarrow Z(G)$ given by $\varphi(x) = x^p$ is a homomorphism. Assume also that we know that if $G$ is not abelian, then ker $\varphi$ has order either $p^2$ or $p^3$. How can we deduce the same information about ker $\varphi$ in the case that $G$ is abelian but not cyclic? That is, why can't ker $\varphi$ have order 1 or $p$?

Comment: If $G$ is abelian, of order $p^3$, and not cyclic, then $G$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb Z/(p)\oplus \mathbb Z/(p^2)$ or $(\mathbb Z/(p))^3$.  In both cases, $\ker \varphi$  is easy to compute explicitly.

Comment: @Aaron In the first case, there are $p^2$ possibilities for $(a, b)$ such that $(a, b)^p = (0, 0)$, and in the second case $p^3$ possibilities such that $(a, b, c)^p = (0, 0, 0)$? Is that it?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct.  I don't know what you are allowed to assume at this point (the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups may not be available to you yet,  However, without any big hammers you can at least get that $G$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathb Z/(p)$, which rules out $|\ker \varphi|=1$.  If you aren't cyclic, can you argue that you can find at least two copies of $\mathbb Z/(p)$ in $G$ that intersect trivially?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I can assume the Fundamental Theorem of finite(ly generated) abelian groups.